# Action economy on spells

Tags: dnd-5e, spellcasting, action-economy

I've had a recent discussion regarding the possibility of using a bonus action, while casting a spell with a casting time of 10 min.

I haven't been able to find anything, so I'm curious to what you guys think?

Comment: I've marked your question as a dupe because I think it has been asked before. This isn't a bad thing as this question might help others find that one. If that question doesn't answer it for you, please clarify for us how and why, and we'll see what needs to be done to help you.